# How to Scrape Different Class names which has same pattern

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a web page. However the class names are not exactly same, but it follows a similar pattern.  Class names are like below

views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd clearfix

views-row views-row-2 views-row-even clearfix

views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd clearfix

I tried the below code but no luck! may be i am using the syntax wrong.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('http://news.mit.edu/topic/artificial-intelligence2').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
match = soup.find_all('li', class_='views-row views-row-* views-row-* clearfix')
print(match)
```

Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you just find all `li` and then filter out those with a class that doesn't start with `'views-row'` or something?

Comment: I'm not an Expert but try using the xpath I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter class value by [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) expression:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://news.mit.edu/topic/artificial-intelligence2').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

li_tags = soup.find_all('li', class_= re.compile(r'views-row views-row-[0-9]+ views-row-(odd|even) clearfix'))
print(li_tags)
```

---

For a more simplified search you may apply `soup.select` with css selector:

```
li_tags = soup.select('li[class*=views-row-]')
print(li_tags)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. You helped me a lot.